# Django: How to create a model that contains a foreign key with CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

If possible, I want to make a model that includes the foreign key with class-based CreateView. I know it can be done using a function.

**models.py**

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return "/pizzas"

class Topping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("pizza", kwargs={"pizza_id": self.pizza.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
class NewTopping(CreateView):
    model = Topping
    template_name = "pizzas/new_topping.html"
    form_class = ToppingForm
```

**urls.py**

```
path("topping/<pk>/create",views.NewTopping.as_view(),name="new_topping")
```

**forms.py**

```
class ToppingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = ['name']
```

**template**

```
 <form action="{% url 'new_topping' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

I've tried to do it like this, but I get an integrity error when I try to save the new instance:

NOT NULL constraint failed: pizzas_topping.pizza_id

Comment: You did not include your form. The problem is probably there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a logical point of view, I would suggest, that you change your models, because a pizza can contain several toppings and a topping can be on several pizzas. So I would suggest, that you add a ManyToManyField "toppings" to your Pizza model and delete the ForeignKeyField to the Pizza model in the Topping model (see code below). If you implement it with your models, you will maybe run into problems.

Each object in the Topping table is only connected with one Pizza object. So if you have for example tomato sauce as a Topping, you have to add multiple objects with the name 'tomato sauce', each connected to a different type of Pizza. If you have for example 'Pizza Margherita', 'Pizza Funghi' and 'Pizza Prosciutto' as Pizza instances, you should have three instances of 'tomato sauce' in your Topping table in the database, because each of the three Pizzas has tomato sauce on it.

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to represent the many-to-many relationship.

So, with a ManyToManyField, Django creates a table (which you don't see as a Model representation) which stores - in your case and with my suggestion - the ID of the Pizza and the ID of the Topping. For further explanation on ManyToManyFields, check the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
#models.py
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
    ...

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
```

Regarding your question:

You don't include the ForeignKeyField inside the forms.py file you created. Change your forms.py file as follows:

```
class ToppingForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Topping
    fields = '__all__'
```

Now you should see a Dropdown or something else, where you can select the Pizza object you would like to add and then, this error shouldn't appear. By default, all defined fields in a model aren't nullable. If you want to make them nullable, you have to define null=True ([Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#null))

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'll be sure to take a look at it in greater depth. I've added both the HTML and the forms.py file

Comment: @DusanMijailovic I have adapted my answer. You need to include the ForeignKeyField inside the form.

Comment: Thank you, this works! And is there a way for Django to automatically realize that for example, I've selected the 'Funghi' pizza model and automatically associate the new topping that I created with that model -  eg. tomato with the 'Funghi' model without requesting the user to select it from the drop-down menu?

Comment: Hmm if I understand you right, you want to let the user select the toppings and afterwards you want some code that automatically detects, which Pizza the user wants (based on his topping)? You could implement something like that, but I don't understand, why you wanted to do this? Maybe I don't get your question right :)

Comment: Not quite. What I made is a list of pizzas, 'Funghi', 'Margarita' etc. When I enter a certain pizza I would like to enter the topping inside of the Pizza model. So, for example, when I go inside the 'Funghi' pizza I get a list of toppings, and after I click on the add topping button, it automatically associates the topping with that pizza instead of me selecting it from the drop-down menu. >https://snipboard.io/WjoeSz.jpg . Hope you can understand the idea from the screenshot :)

Comment: I would really advise you, that you implement this with a ManyToManyField... This makes things like these much easier. And after all it is the correct way of implementing these types of relationships between entities.